# Google Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

How to retrieve the Chromedevices assigned to a Calendar? I can retrieve the list of chrome devices or calendars under my domain but could not find the association between calendars and assigned devices?

Comment: What do you mean by association between calendars and assigned devices? And what method did you use to get the list of devices/calendars under your own domain?

Comment: If you browse Google Admin Console, you can see your chrome devices and assign a calendar to each device for your domain (company). I am not able to find a Google Admin SDK API to give me that mapping between calendars and Chrome device serial numbers?